# How to use different views in same activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am new in development, I am making quiz app to students and I need your recommendation:

When TestActivity is opened student see different types of questions: some of them just check boxes, some "yes"/"no" buttons, some editTexts to allow to student to input correct answer.

Student see just 1 task at same time, when student presses button "next" next task opens.

For reason that every type of question contains different views I need to change that views very often inside of same Activity. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. Use different types of Fragments, each using a different layout
2. Programmatically create the Views and set their visibility
3. Change the layout of the Activity every time.